# Java Util Logging File Configuration Conundrum

Tags: java.util.logging

My log.properties contains configuration

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = logs/startup.%g.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 10000000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 3

GtfsOperatorManager.level=INFO
TripUpdate.level=FINER
VehiclePosition.level=INFO
Alert.level=INFO
```

where the root logger logs to a file called *startup* and other loggers such as *TripUpdate* are set up programmatically to log to their own files.

The problem is that as shown log entries only go into *TripUpdate* at level *INFO* . However if I comment out the line

```
#java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = INFO
```

then *TripUpdate* logs at *FINER* as configured but log entries then go into the *startup* log at *FINER* too rather than *INFO*.

What am I doing wrong, how do I get *startup* logging at *INFO* and *TripUpdate* logging at FINER ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the root logger level in your config file by adding the following:

```
.level=INFO
```

All child loggers will [inherit this level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getLevel--).

> However if I comment out the line [snip] then TripUpdate logs at FINER as configured but log entries then go into the startup log at FINER too rather than INFO.

This is because the default [`java.util.logging.FileHandler.level`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) is `ALL`.

Since your are doing programmatic configurations too you need to make sure you are keeping your logger from being garbage collected.

> No logging is not done directly to startup above, rather it inherits log entries but I want to filter out everything above INFO

You have limited options there.  You can use [setUseParentHandlers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#setUseParentHandlers-boolean-) on the loggers that you don't want to see output from.  This can be done from the properties file by setting [`<loggername>.useParentHandlers=false`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html).  You can then attach an additional file handler to the logger that is no longer publishing records to the parent handlers.

Otherwise, you have to just write a [log filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Filter.html) to check the [logger name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html#getLoggerName--) and [level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html#getLevel--) and install it on the file handler.

Comment: Afraid setting .level=INFO doesn't work. It looks as if java.util.logging.FileHandler.level  is the determining factor and log level is being ignored. No logging is not done directly to startup above, rather it inherits log entries but I want to filter out everything above INFO